# D3 - Align value label inside ordinal chart

Tags: d3.js

I want to align the value of each bar on top of it but I can't align the middle of the label text with the middle of the rect.

```
function createBarChart(panel, cs_data) {
  var data = [
   {
      "label":"1998",
      "value":"0.2301495972382"
   },
   {
      "label":"1999",
      "value":"0.12531328320802"
   },
   ....
   {
      "label":"2011",
      "value":"0.4907688712316"
   }];

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
      width = parseInt(panel.getWidth()) - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = parseInt(panel.getHeight()) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011])
      .rangeBands([0, width], .1);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, max])
      .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

  d3.select(".chart").selectAll("*").remove();

  var chart = d3.select(".chart")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);


  chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

  chart.selectAll('.text')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value.toFixed(2); });
}
```

Comment: In order for someone to reproduce your code, we'll need to know what your data looks like...

Comment: ok thats right, I made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take into account the size of the `<text>`:

```
chart.selectAll('.text')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return parseFloat(d.value).toFixed(2); })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.label) + x.rangeBand()/2 - this.getComputedTextLength() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) - 10; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRCnQtIpRpnV3gGK52IO?p=preview).